# Best practice (or advice) on one server, three SSH login, one remote Git repo

Tags: linux, git

Background info:

- We are currently 3 web programmers (good, real-life friends, no distrust issues).
- Each programmers SSH into the single Linux server, where the code resides, under their own username with sudo powers.
- We all use work on the different files at one time. We ask the question "Are you in the file __?" sometimes. We use Vim so we know if the file is opened or not.
- Our development code (no production yet) resides in /var/www/
- Currently I set up **one** local Git repo under /var/repos/.
- Our remote repo is hosted on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).
- I am *very* new to Git. I used subversion before but I was basically spoon-fed instructions and was told exactly what to type to sync up codes and commit.
- I read about half of Scott Chacon's [*Pro Git*](http://progit.org/) and that's the extent to most of my Git knowledge.
- In case it matters, we run Ubuntu 11.04, Apache 2.2.17, and Git 1.7.4.1.

I am starting to think what I need to do is have 3 separate local repos located under each user's home directory (remember this is still all on the same one server). But would that still make sense if we all work on the same website code on /var/www/?

Also some slightly related question:

- From my understanding, am I suppose to directly modify my local repo (so that means in order to debug, my repo needs to be visible from a browser by residing in /var/www/), or am I suppose to just manually copy edited files from development directory and overwrite my local repo to track, commit, then push?
- If I am suppose to copy from my local repo, can I just copy and overwrite the whole development directory and let Git figure out which ones are untracked (I don't think this was possible with subversion)? Or do I still need to keep track of edited files manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal setup would be:

- Each developer have their local working copy wherever they want; probably their desktops, because it's always faster to work locally than over ssh.
- Central, bare, repository on the server (in `/var/repos`).
- A `post-update` hook in the central repository, that will update `/var/www` when push to master is done. There are two ways:

  - Using `git archive` and `tar` to copy the files over
  - Having `/var/www/` as a repository/checkout and run `git update` in it.

  The later is easier and the only downside is that you have to configure your web server to block the `.git` directory.

But you can start with making `/var/www/` a working directory—just `git init`, `git add .` and `git commit` there—and gradually switch from there.

Add aditional questions: Git has a list of files it knows about. If you just wipe everything except `.git` and put in new content, it will sort it out. But making `/var/www` a repository is easier; preventing `.git` to be visible from the browser can easily be done by configuring the server or even just permissions (just set the `.git` directory user and group to one the www server does not have but you do and set permissions to 770).

Comment: Okay so that means each developer needs their own local LAMP stack on their machine for local testing. It won't be a much of a problem to migrate the code to the local repo, but what about the database? We run MySQL and our application only has 2 tables that is easily populated with a Python script, but in the future when copying the database may not be an option, then should we connect remotely to the server's database? Or should we just have a sample data for testing? Thanks for the response!

Comment: @hobbes3: You can have either, it does not matter. Just have a local, unversioned, config file with the database connection settings and switch as needed. In fact I'd probably eventually have both local db with sample data for testing schema and other disruptive changes and one with representative data for testing under realistic load.